How to prove that nth derivative of given function at zero is zero?
let $k,n$ be a natural numbers with $k>n$ and $f_m(x)$ be a function such that
$$f_m(0)=0 , f_m^{(p)}(0)\in R , \space \forall \space m\in\{1,2,...,k\} \space \wedge \space p\in\{1,2,...,n\}$$
then how can I prove that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \prod_{m=1}^k f_m(x)=0$$
I used special case of that in this Question for $f_m(x)=e^x-1$
Leibniz Rule show that to derivative all $f_m(x)$ at least one time it need to be $k\ge n$
So if $k<n$ then there exist $f_m^{(0)}(x)$ which made it zero.
but this prove is not fine So how can I prove it in better way ?
and How can we prove it without using Leibniz Rule ?

We generally say $f_m$ is a sequence of functions, and only call $f_m$ "a function" if we write it as $f(m,x)$ rather than $f_m(x).$

Why are you taking the limit of the $n^\text{th}$ derivative as $x\to 0$ rather than just calculating the derivative at $x=0$? And why would you want to avoid using the Leibniz rule?

@TedShifrin taking the limit at zero or the the function at $x=0$ isn't the same ?! and I don't avoid that rule but its better to prove it without any theorem (without prove it) since the problem seems simple

Maybe consider the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ of the product function.

@TedShifrin yes that's good idea I didn't think about that
